UK visitor visa bank statement
We would visite UK for 1month with my boyfriend. We have good friend who would like to sponsor our trip for both of us (flight, accomodation,…). So, I don’t know how much many should we have on our bank statement to get the visa.

It is not just about the amount in your bank account or savings but more how much money you regularly get in and how much you spend.

Your good friend needs to submit his/her bank statements, as well as provide a really good reason why he has decided to pay for your vacation.

Thank you. Is it enough to have £1000 on our account? We would spend maybe £500 during our vacation (1month). Is it good? @Willeke

Yes, he already did it. But what we don't know the most is: is the amount contained in our bank still essential even if we already have a sponsor? @DJClayworth

There is no known amount, it does depend on many things, like your income, the actual costs of the travel. Imagine your friend not coming up with the money you should be able to survive and 500 pound does not sound like enough.

What I mean is £500 each, which makes our entire cost with my boyfriend £1000 for a month, knowing that our friend is already paying for the accommodation.
If not, how much will it take? @Willeke
